# Error while downloading torch vision, used official command from pytorch but does not work

Tags: python, deep-learning, torchvision

I tried different solutions but it does not work, I tried to download torchvision with pip but it does not work,  the problem can be seen from the screenshot given below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRHz5.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Unistall torch and torchvision:

```
pip unistall torch
pip unistall torchvision
```

2. Upgrade pip

`pip install --upgrade pip`

3. Create a `requirements.txt` file like this:

```
torch
torchvision
```

4. Install them.

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

5. Pip will resolve the dependencies automatically for you. Post your results from step 4 please.

Comment: Thanks for your coment, I resolved my issue by installing python version of 3.7.9.